# onClick not working reactjs in button despite binding

Tags: reactjs, button, buttonclick

I created a new component in my Reactjs code and have a button there with onClick function. But the onClick function does not work. I tried everything but it still does not work. Any ideas how I can go about solving this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.openMenuBar = this.openMenuBar.bind(this);
}

openMenuBar(){
    console.log("open");
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.openMenuBar()}}>
                <MenuIcon/>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

This component is then called in the app.js

```
<HeaderComponent/>
```

**UPDATE**

Some helful info: Whenever I route it to a path (app/path/xx), then the button is not clickable. Otherwise, is it clickable (if the path is root)

Comment: You are mixing both sintaxes. Try `onClick={() => this.clickHandler()}` or `onClick={() => {return this.clickHandler()}}` or even `onClick={this.clickHandler}`.

Comment: I don't think the code posted by @Thanatos is wrong, because essentially he is declaring an anonymous arrow function, inside which he is referencing and calling `openMenuBar`.

Comment: I did everything mentioned in the first comment.. Still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be

```
onClick={this.openMenuBar}
```

Or

```
onClick={() => { return this.openMenuBar()}}
```

Or

```
onClick={() => this.openMenuBar() }
```

```js
class MenuIcon extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <i className="fas fa-plus" />
  }
}
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.openMenuBar = this.openMenuBar.bind(this);
    }
     
    openMenuBar(){
      console.log("open");
    }

    render(){
      return(
          <div>
            
            <button onClick={this.openMenuBar}> <MenuIcon /></button>
            <button onClick={() => this.openMenuBar()}> btn2</button>
            <button onClick={() => { return this.openMenuBar()}}> btn3</button>
            
          </div>
    );
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<HeaderComponent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: tried this.. For some reason the button is not clickable no matter what.. Issue still remains..

Comment: I updated the answer, that I can work. I think the problem is the `<MenuIcon/>`

Comment: I added the  `<MenuIcon />` to test and don't see any issue. You can run my snippet.

Comment: This is irrespective of <MenuIcon> . Even after removing it I face the same issue. The button is not clickable no matter what.

Comment: I think I got a clue. Whenever I route it to a path (app/path/xx), then the button is not clickable. Otherwise, is it clickabe (if the path is root)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
openmenubar = () => {

...

}
```

and

```
<button onClick = { () => this.openmenubar() } > </button>
```

Comment: Can you try without binding function in constructor ? arrow function binds it automatically and can you try it without MenuIcon ?